# what is the best way to import 2.5 million of rows from mysql to mongodb

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I want to migrate `mysql` `data` to my `mongodb` server.
There is a  `table` named `shop_product` having 2.5 million of `rows`.

Question:I want to get these `rows` in `mongodb` ,what's the best way ?

**More Description:**

Actually I have created a php script for the same operation.I created a function in that . When i try to fetch 2.5 million of rows from mysql in a limit of 100000 records in one time and then i recall the same function(recursion) with offset parameter.It throws error "Fatal Error: Out of memory "

Comment: No it does'nt solve my problem

Comment: Actually I have created a php script for the same operation.I created a function in that . When i try to fetch 2.5 million of rows from mysql in a limit of 100000 records in one time and then i recall the same function(recursion) with `offset` parameter.It throws error "Fatal Error: Out of memory "

Comment: Can you try MongoVUE. I have imported small amout of data using this. Not sure it will work for this much records, http://www.mongovue.com/2010/07/30/import-data-from-mysql/